# Inferencing DataType Properties

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I'm new to this ontology. I m using protege now. I have 2 classes BT and Document. I have created 2 Object Property 1. topic (Domain:Document , Range:BT) 2. hasDocument (Inverse property of topic).

I have created 1 DataType Property called title (Domain:Document Range:Literal).

Following are the Samples for the properties which I have created

1. BT hasDocument Document
2. Document topic BT
3. Document title "TestingName"

I dont know how to create a property which infers the following result

BT newProperty "TestingName"

Comment: Duplicated on http://answers.semanticweb.com as [Inference OWL](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/26526/inference-owl).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you're looking to be able to infer from

```
docX topic someTopic 
docX title "SampleTitle"
someTopic hasDocumentWithTitle "SampleTitle"
```

You could almost do this with an property chain, by asserting that `hasDocumentWithTitle` has as a subproperty the chain `(inverse topic) o title`.  Unfortunately, in OWL property chains can't end with datatype properties, so you can't do this.  However, you can use SWRL rules, and many OWL2 reasoners process SWRL rules.  You'd use a rule of the form:

> topic(?doc,?topic) ∧ title(?doc,?title) → hasDocumentWithTitle(?topic,?title)

For instance we can get the following result in Protege with the following ontology:

[image: result in Protege]

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rule-example="http://www.example.org/rule-example#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:swrl="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#"
    xmlns:swrlb="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrlb#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.example.org/rule-example"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.org/rule-example#Document"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.org/rule-example#Topic"/>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.example.org/rule-example#hasTopic"/>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.example.org/rule-example#hasTitle"/>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.example.org/rule-example#hasDocumentWithTitle"/>
  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.example.org/rule-example#doc42">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/rule-example#Document"/>
    <rule-example:hasTitle>Document Number Forty-Two</rule-example:hasTitle>
    <rule-example:hasTopic>
      <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.example.org/rule-example#topic101">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/rule-example#Topic"/>
        <rule-example:hasTopic rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/rule-example#topic101"/>
      </owl:NamedIndividual>
    </rule-example:hasTopic>
  </owl:NamedIndividual>
  <swrl:Imp>
    <swrl:head>
      <swrl:AtomList>
        <rdf:rest rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#nil"/>
        <rdf:first>
          <swrl:DatavaluedPropertyAtom>
            <swrl:propertyPredicate rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/rule-example#hasDocumentWithTitle"/>
            <swrl:argument2>
              <swrl:Variable rdf:about="urn:swrl#title"/>
            </swrl:argument2>
            <swrl:argument1>
              <swrl:Variable rdf:about="urn:swrl#topic"/>
            </swrl:argument1>
          </swrl:DatavaluedPropertyAtom>
        </rdf:first>
      </swrl:AtomList>
    </swrl:head>
    <swrl:body>
      <swrl:AtomList>
        <rdf:rest>
          <swrl:AtomList>
            <rdf:rest rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#nil"/>
            <rdf:first>
              <swrl:DatavaluedPropertyAtom>
                <swrl:propertyPredicate rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/rule-example#hasTitle"/>
                <swrl:argument1>
                  <swrl:Variable rdf:about="urn:swrl#doc"/>
                </swrl:argument1>
                <swrl:argument2 rdf:resource="urn:swrl#title"/>
              </swrl:DatavaluedPropertyAtom>
            </rdf:first>
          </swrl:AtomList>
        </rdf:rest>
        <rdf:first>
          <swrl:IndividualPropertyAtom>
            <swrl:propertyPredicate rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/rule-example#hasTopic"/>
            <swrl:argument1 rdf:resource="urn:swrl#doc"/>
            <swrl:argument2 rdf:resource="urn:swrl#topic"/>
          </swrl:IndividualPropertyAtom>
        </rdf:first>
      </swrl:AtomList>
    </swrl:body>
  </swrl:Imp>
</rdf:RDF>
```